# Trouble calculating difference of results from nested sub queries and getting a syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

If I run each query individually I will get results, however, when I try and do a nested query I continue to get a syntax error.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Here is a copy of the query I am trying to run.

```
Select 
    P.Part_Type, P.Number, P.mold, 
    dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Result as Val1, 
    dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Result as Val2, 
    ((Val1 - Val2) / 60) As DIFF
From 
    (Select 
         P.Part_Type, P.Number, P.mold, dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Result as Val1
     from
         dbo.tbl_Parts P 
     inner join
         dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data on P.Parts_ID = dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Part
     where 
         (P.Part_Type = 'Shell PS') 
         and (dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Msmt_Spec = 7327)

     union all

     select 
         P.Part_Type, P.Number, P.mold, dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Result as Val2
     from
         dbo.tbl_Parts P 
     inner join
         dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data on P.Parts_ID = dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Part
     where 
         (P.Part_Type = 'Shell PS') 
         and (dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Msmt_Spec = 7326)
)
```

I have tried removing the aliases for the parts table. I have tried only selecting Val2 on the second query. At this point, I'm not sure what else I can do.

Here is an example of from the results for Val1

[image: Sample data]

Here's a sampling of data from tbl_parts and tbl_msmt_data

[image: tbl_parts]
[image: tbl_msmt_data]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  There is probably a simpler way to write this query . . . if it were clear what you wanted to do.

Comment: You need to alias your derived table `FROM ( SELECT... ) AS MyTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Part_Type, 
    Number, 
    mold, 
    Val1, 
    Val2, 
    ( ( Val1 - Val2 ) / 60 ) AS DIFF -- possible divide by zero exception!
FROM (

    SELECT 
        P.Part_Type, P.Number, P.mold, ISNULL ( M.Result, 0 ) AS Val1, 0 AS Val2
    FROM dbo.tbl_Parts AS P 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data AS M
        ON P.Parts_ID = M.Part
    WHERE 
        P.Part_Type = 'Shell PS' 
        AND M.Msmt_Spec = 7327
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        P.Part_Type, P.Number, P.mold, 0 AS Val1, ISNULL ( M.Result, 0 ) AS Val2
    FROM dbo.tbl_Parts AS P 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data AS M
        ON P.Parts_ID = M.Part
    WHERE 
        P.Part_Type = 'Shell PS'
        AND M.Msmt_Spec = 7326

) AS MyTable;
```

**UPDATE:**

*I had to mark the answer as unresolved because I found an issue with the solution that I didn't see earlier. When it does the query, it will display two entries for each number, one row will have Val 1 be null and Val 2 have a number.*

To return a single row for Msmt_Spec values 7326 and 7327, you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
    Part_Type, 
    Number, 
    Mold, 
    Val1, 
    Val2, 
    ( ( Val1 - Val2 ) / 60 ) AS DIFF
FROM (

    SELECT
        P.Part_Type, P.Number, P.Mold
        , MAX ( CASE WHEN M.Msmt_Spec = 7327 THEN M.Result ELSE 0 END ) AS Val1
        , MAX ( CASE WHEN M.Msmt_Spec = 7326 THEN M.Result ELSE 0 END ) AS Val2
    FROM dbo.tbl_Parts AS P
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data AS M
        ON P.Parts_ID = M.Part
    WHERE 
        P.Part_Type = 'Shell PS'
        AND M.Msmt_Spec IN ( 7326, 7327 )
    GROUP BY
        Part_Type, Number, Mold

) AS MyTable
ORDER BY
    Part_Type, Number;
```

My testing results (limited set of data) returned the following:

```
+-----------+--------+------+------+------+------+
| Part_Type | Number | Mold | Val1 | Val2 | DIFF |
+-----------+--------+------+------+------+------+
| Shell PS  |   2200 |    2 | 1000 |  847 |    2 |
| Shell PS  |   2201 |    3 | 1608 | 1500 |    1 |
| Shell PS  |   2202 |    1 |  225 |   45 |    3 |
| Shell PS  |   2203 |    4 | 1015 |  909 |    1 |
| Shell PS  |   2204 |    2 | 1615 | 1447 |    2 |
+-----------+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

Is this what you were looking to achieve?

Comment: I tried this but received the following errors
 Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "P.Part_Type" could not be bound. 
 
 Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "P.Number" could not be bound. 
 
 Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "P.mold" could not be bound. 
 
 Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Result" could not be bound.The multi-part identifier "dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Result" could not be bound.

Comment: The multi-part identifier "dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Result" could not be bound. 
 
 Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "dbo.tbl_Msmt_Data.Result" could not be bound. 
 
 Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'Val2'.

Comment: I had a typo. Try my updated answer. Oh, the Val2 error makes sense as the first SELECT of your union aliases the column as Va1. Let me give this a look.

Comment: It is still giving errors:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "P.Part_Type" could not be bound. 
 
 Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "P.Number" could not be bound. 
 
 Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "P.mold" could not be bound. 
 
 Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'Val2'. 
 
 Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'Val2'.

Comment: Can you share some of the data from tbl_Parts and tbl_Msmt_Data?

Comment: @vxd128 I totally missed the outer alias. Try my updated answer.

Comment: Parts_ID Part_Type Number Mold Date_Created Product Associated Traveler_Printed Blade Status Date_Status_Updated FWF Tg Cure Graph Comments Scrap Tag_Color In_Use Anc_Assoc SSMA_TimeStamp Pending_Shipped Pending_Shipped_Date Shipped Shipped_Date Received Received_Date
87218 Shell PS 2147 4 12/18/2019 56.9 0 0 87006 WIP 12/18/2019 0 0 0 HEAT START AT 17:25 END AT 2155 0 Red -1   


ID Part Msmt_Spec   Initial Value  Repaired Value Product Result Result_Repaired NCR   Comments Time_Completed User_Name  LSL USL 
5839146 101470 7327 1930 56.9 1930 9/9/2020 7:36:01 PM SDBay1WI4  0 2399

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @vxd128 Glad to help! I realized I could simplify my answer a little more, so I did. Rather than NULL for Val1 or Val2, I used 0 (as you're doing math) and avoided the additional checks for ISNULL in the outer side of the query.

Comment: Tried that new code and it gave these errors:
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
 
 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: @vxd128 Yep. Fixed it. Try again.

Comment: @CriticalError I'm a bit perplexed by `( ( Val1 - Val2 ) / 60 ) AS DIFF -- possible divide by zero exception!`. Although SQL Server can create divide-by-zero errors in creative ways (Try `select 30 / 3 / 5; select 30 / -3 / 5;`.), I don't see how `60` becomes `0`. May I have a hint?

Comment: @HABO You're right. My thought was if Val1 - Val2 = 0 it would cause a division error, but it's actually the reverse ( 60 / 0 ) that's true. I'll leave the comment as the answer has been accepted, but it can be safely ignored.

Comment: @CriticalError I see what you are saying regarding this. I also realized that I never mentioned that Val1 - Val2 can never be 0, it can be positive or negative.

Comment: @CriticalError I had to mark the answer as unresolved because I found an issue with the solution that I didn't see earlier. When it does the query, it will display two entries for each number, one row will have Val 1 be null and Val 2 have a number. The opposite is true for the second. I'm including that I'm seeing. 
Part_Type Number mold Val1   Val2 DIFF
Shell PS       2630          1       NULL   802 -13.3666666666667
Shell PS       2630           1        955  NULL 15.9166666666667

I would appreciate it if you could take another look at it.

Comment: @vxd128 I'm happy to help. Because I don't have data to test against, I can't catch these types of results. Would you update your question to include data from tbl_Parts, please?

Comment: @CriticalError I have included some same data from the tables. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @CriticalError I was off for the past few days and just now had a chance to review this. This worked perfectly. Thank you again for your assistance. I'm still new on the SQL query building side of things so seeing how you did this will help me in the future.